# Magento 1.9 GET parameters in product view

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have an observer action setup, that checks if a product page is loaded. If so, it calls a custom help that deals with all of the GET paremeters. It used to work for over 4 years and have suddenly stopped (the only thing that changed on the 3rd party's side is the naming of those parameters).

**Here is the observer action:**

```
 public function productView($observer) {

        /*@var $block Mage_Core_Block_Abstract*/
        $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();

        if ($block && $this->getProduct()){
            if ($block->getModuleName() == 'Mage_Catalog'){

                $productId = $this->getProduct()->getEntityId();

                //If params exist - save
                if ($this->ParamsHelper()->saveParams($productId)){
                    //code omitted
                }
            }
        }

}
```

**Here is the helper's action:**

```
public function saveParams($productId) {
    if (is_numeric($productId)){

        $params = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams();
        if (!empty($params['image']) && !empty($params['config'])){

            //never gets here
            return true;

        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

If I try to var_dump the `$params`, I get the following array which only includes product_id:

```
array(1) { ["id"]=> string(3) "664" }
```

Expected result is to be able to access all the GET parameters passed via url in product view.

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

**EDIT**

Product URLs are similar to product names, like f.e.:

```
domain.com/red-jacket
```

In a perfect case, I would expect to get parameters passed like following:

```
domain.com/red-jacket?param1=aaa&param2=bbb
```

Comment: Default in product view page only one parameter is passed www.domain.com/catalog/product/view/id/664 , so you are also passed other parameter in the url.

Comment: I have updated the question with URL examples.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure whats the exact problem is ... but for `domain.com/red-jacket?param1=aaa&param2=bbb` you can get parameters in this way:

```
$params = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams();
$param1 = $params['param1']
or
$param1 = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('param1');
```

Answer (score 1):

//code for get parameters in view page.

```
$arrParams = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams();
echo "Get Parameter"; echo '<pre>', print_r($arrParams);
```